# Picture position

Tags: html, css

I would need help with the setting position of the image:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```

For this code:

```
<ion-view title="Title">
    <ion-content class="scroll has-header>
        <div class="list">
            <a ng-repeat="champ in freeChamps" href="#/champ/{{ champ.id }}" class="item item-avatar" href="#">
              <img src="http://lkimg.zamimg.com/images/v2/champions/icons/size64x64/{{ champ.id }}.png">
            </a>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is my page: http://paliaktest.netne.net/www/
I want it to look like this: http://lolrotation.ovh/rfreekr (1 2 3 4 5 - first line, 6 7 8 9 10 - second line

Comment: You'll need to reproduce the issue HERE. Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: So this is the CSS from that website `body{display:block;margin:0px;}div{width:100%}div img{width:20%;display:block;float:left}` would there be anything else?

Comment: I know you're new to Stack Overflow, so you might now know about this, but it is customary to accept an answer "because it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution", by clicking the checkmark that is below the up and down vote arrows.  Please also see this Stack Overflow Article: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: BTW, I'm not trying to get more Rep - feel free to accept the other answer - I just wanted to let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on Alan Etian's comment, but with a few changes.

---

You need to set these CSS rules:

1. `img` needs rules: `width: 20%;` and `float: left;`
2. `body` needs rule: `margin: 0px;`
3. That's it!

This will work for your page you linked to in the comments.

---

Here's a: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9rketsep/1/)

And here's the CSS code:

`body{margin:0px;}img{width:20%;float:left}`

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/hryqo6d7/

I made this quick one for you. 
It's two rows of pictures. If you want them to be 1/5 of the window, I suggest using javascript for it.

it basically comes down to this css

```
.icons {
  text-align:center;
}
.icons > img {
  height: 100px;
}
```